# Jquery Circle Progress Bar text new line

Tags: jquery, text, progress-bar, newline, geometry

Hi Guys I'm working on jQuery Circle Progress Bar (Circlefuljs Plugin) by refering https://github.com/pguso/jquery-plugin-circliful, in this every thing works fine, In this I'm having a text parameter where I can give some string text that will show inside the circle, My issue is if my text size is big the text is overlaping outside of the circle, So I'm trying to give an new line, but it is not working, please see my snippet here https://jsfiddle.net/heh12u5v/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/circliful/1.0.2/js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:400px">
    <div id="test-circle"></div>
</div>
var value = 75
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-circle").circliful({
    animationStep: 5,
    foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
    backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
    percent: value,
    iconPosition: 'middle',
    text: "This circle \n for demo",
  });
});
```

I tried by using `\n` in the text parameter so it can be break to new line, but it is not working, so guys please help me to sort out this solution, it will be very great full for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use textStyle, it's on the documentation with this you can give whatever you want with the css style of the text

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-circle").circliful({
    animationStep: 5,
    foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
    backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
    percent: value,
    iconPosition: 'middle',
    textStyle: 'font-size:8px;',
    text: "This circle for demo",
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This plugin convert your text to **SVG** image text. You can add multiline with `</tspan>` tag. And place correctly your main text x,y with **jquery** `attr()` parameter.

You can find more informations here: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/svg-text-layout/9781491933817/ch04.html

Please try below. Working fine.

```js
var value = 75
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-circle").circliful({
    animationStep: 5,
    foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
    backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
    percent: value,
    iconPosition: 'middle',
    text: 'This circle <tspan  y="113" x="101">for demo</tspan>'
  });
  $(".circliful text:eq(0)").attr("y",94)
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/circliful/1.0.2/css/jquery.circliful.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/circliful/1.0.2/js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:400px">
 <div id="test-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If any one face issue text behind the circle then can change this line in main js file -

```
(typeof elements !== 'undefined' ? elements : '') +
'<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="' + settings.fillColor + '" stroke="' + settings.backgroundColor + '" stroke-width="' + backgroundBorderWidth + '" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />' +
```

on line number - 416 to

```
'<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="57" class="border" fill="' + settings.fillColor + '" stroke="' + settings.backgroundColor + '" stroke-width="' + backgroundBorderWidth + '" stroke-dasharray="360" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />' +
(typeof elements !== 'undefined' ? elements : '') +
```